# How to use stripe checkout page in google sites

Tags: stripe-payments, google-sites

I have a website created using google sites. I would like to know how to integrate stripe in my Page. Is it possible ? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using Checkout requires having a back-end server to manage [creating the Checkout session](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=checkout#redirect-customers), and optionally handling the redirect (you can also redirect client-side).

If you don't have a back-end server, I'd recommend looking at [Payment Links](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links) instead, which use Checkout but don't require a server integration. You can create a re-usable link for placing on your webpage that users click to enter the checkout flow.